# executing a shell every minute using cron

Tags: bash, cron

i want to run this bash code every minute using cron. I saved it onto `/root/activate.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in /home/user/torrents/*.torrent

do
if [ "$file" != "/home/user/torrents/*.torrent" ]; then
echo [`date`] "$file" added to queue. >> /var/log/torrentwatch.log
/usr/bin/transmission-remote localhost:9091 -a "$file"
mv "$file" "$file".added
sleep 1
fi
done
```

permission is set `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root                 278 May 27 01:27 activate.sh`

then inside my `crontab -e` i placed this

`* * * * * root sh /root/activate.sh`

**the script does not execute and i get this log error**

```
May 27 01:40:02 media CRON[3556]: (root) CMD (root sh /root/activate.sh)
May 27 01:40:02 media CRON[3555]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
---after a minute---
May 27 01:41:01 media CRON[3582]: (root) CMD (root sh /root/activate.sh)
May 27 01:41:01 media CRON[3581]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, why aren't you just using transmission's watch-dir feature?

The crontab entry is wrong, it should be `* * * * * /root/activate.sh` when you add it with `crontab -e`. `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d/*` takes an extra username field, but the user specific crontabs which you set with the `crontab` command, does not have a username field; the jobs are run as the user that ran `crontab`.

Also, since this script operates on files in user's homedir, I would've run the job as that user. There's nothing about that script that requires root permissions, apart from maybe writing to that log file, but you can just change ownership of that logfile instead.

As for the script, I'd modify it a bit:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ~user/torrents/*.torrent; do
    [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue
    transmission-remote -a "$file" && mv "$file" "$file.added" || continue
    printf '[%s] %s added to queue\n' "$(date)" "$file"
    sleep 1
done >> /var/log/torrentwatch.log
```

Lastly, you should avoid adding extensions for scripts, and especially not use `.sh` when the script is a bash script, not an sh script.

Comment: thank you sir!! 
watch-dir feature is already defined in `settings.json` and it doesn't seem to work out for me.. your code is perfect :) would you be so kind to explain what that code does in english? im still trying to learn about bash and yours is too advanced for me to understand :) thanks.

Comment: @user1666411 The main difference is that it checks that transmission-remote succeeds before renaming the file and printing the log message. One reason transmission's watch-dir may fail is when adding files over an external filesystem like NFS. transmission listens for inotify events in the watch-dir, but NFS doesn't trigger inotify events.

Answer (score 3):

When using `crontab -e` you can't specify a username. The format is:

```
m h  dom mon dow   command
```

So you should put this in `crontab -e`:

```
* * * * * /root/activate.sh
```

You don't have to use `sh` because the file has execute permission and a shebang line (#!/bin/bash).